# Will touch behave the same in all systems (overriding an existing file)?

Tags: touch

Just a Cron test command to consider, create an empty file in the user's home directory every minute:

```
* * * * * touch ${HOME}/example.example
```

Will touch behave the same in all systems (overriding an existing file)?

Have you ever came across a Linux in which touch will not override a file but rather create versions such as `filename(1)`, `file_name(2)`, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

All `touch` does is create a file if none exists, or update the mtime on an existing one. It does not create versions. Both provided permissions & path allow.

And having `${HOME}` in the cron line, is asking for trouble.

Comment: There's an obvious problem in that that `$HOME` is not quoted (and cron jobs are run by sh by default where an unquoted parameter expansion invokes split+glob). But otherwise, the `HOME` environment variable is meant to be set in cron jobs to the home directory of the owner of the crontab. So using `touch ~/example.example` or `touch "$HOME/example.example"` should be fine.

Comment: "And having ${HOME} in the cron line, is asking for trouble." -- I'm not sure a statement like this is really helpful without also including _what kind_ of trouble might come up, and _why_. So, why do you think it's asking for trouble?